# Ubuntu 18.04 - wake up after suspend not possible, PC reboots

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. When I try to wake up my suspended workstation it will reboot.

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided the exact model and make of your PC. The model number should be copied from the serial number sticker; model numbers elsewhere are not reliably useful. Please click [edit] when you have that info. Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115572/ubuntu-18-04-dell-xps15-9570-impossible-to-reliably-suspend-hibernate

Comment: Also take a look at this article to see if you may possibly have enabled Hibernate   https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04